# Conditional statement in gdal_calc with result as float, not boolean

Tags: gdal, qgis-2, raster-calculator, qgis-processing, gdal-calc

Many examples on gis.se that refer to gdal_calc give a boolean example.
[example 1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69129/how-to-conditionnally-assign-a-new-value-to-pixels-of-a-raster-image)
[example 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/100013/open-source-python-option-for-arcpys-con-tool)

If I need to calculate a conditional statement on a float:

```
If Raster_Value >= 1024, then 1024; else Raster_Value.
```

How do I perform that operation in the gdal raster calculator command line

**EDIT**
I tried radouxju answer and it worked, except for the cell values that didn't.
here are 3 kinds of results I got

[image]

Here is the tool gui and the parameters I've entered
[image]

Answer (score 5):

you can define the output type using the "type" option

> --type=TYPE           output datatype, must be one of ['Int32', 'Int16',
>                           'Float64', 'UInt16', 'Byte', 'UInt32', 'Float32']

so it would look like this

```
gdal_calc.py -A yourInput.tif --outfile=yourOutput.tif --calc="1024*(A>=1024)+A*(A<1024)" --NoDataValue=0 --type='Float32'
```

Comment: Well, that seemed to work, apart from the fact that certain cells below threshold were changed too.
http://i68.tinypic.com/10pxcig.png

Comment: this is strange. Do you also have unexplained results with Float64 ?

Comment: I have a similar question, so, how can I change the pixel value to entire raster? In SAGA GIS it's simple:  ifelse (a=0,1,a). How to do this via gdal_calc.py?

Comment: I would use "--calc="(a==0)*(1)+(A!=0)*(A)"