# Changing null / no data values

Tags: qgis, reclassify, null

I have a raster where null values are stored as -9999. I want to change these to 0.

Googling suggests this can be done in the raster calculator, but e.g. `(layer name = -9999) * 0` doesn't work. And indeed other pages suggest that any formula including a null will return a null. I've also tried `r.reclass`, reclassify by table and by layer, but none are giving me what I need - which is simply to change -9999 values to 0.

Comment: Check this [`r.null`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.null.html), more details you will find in this thread: [Changing NULL values of raster to 0 in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33764/change-null-values-raster-values-to-0-in-qgis)